# Tic tac toe 2d array filling charachter

Tags: c++11, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to create 4x4 board using tic tac toe and this is the function I'm using.  This function resets the board to default which has to be like this
[default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwCZl.png)

```
void resetBoard(char board[4][4])                                   
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)                                     
    {
        int boardcounter = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = '0' + boardcounter;
            boardcounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

For this i get answer [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZeiE.png)
and if write it like this

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        board[i][j] = (char) boardcounter;
        boardcounter++;
    }
```

the board gets very screwed up how can i change that so that the person can enter character A,...,G which represents 10-16 in the board.

Answer (score 0):

```
void resetBoard(char board[4][4])                                   
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)                                     
    {
        int boardcounter = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            char offset = '0';

            if( boardcounter > 9 )
            {
                offset = 'A' - 10;
            }

            board[i][j] = offset + boardcounter;
            boardcounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the image you posted is the output from the code you posted above.  I had to change the code you posted to get that output:

```
void resetBoard(char board[4][4])
{
    int boardcounter = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = '0' + boardcounter;
            boardcounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

If it's not clear what the change was, I moved the line `int boardcounter = 1;` outside of the loops.

The reason this code produces the output shown in the image you posted has to do with the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) encoding system.

If you look at the table in that link, you can see the ASCII code for '0' is 48.  When boardcounter is 1, the value of `'0' + boardcounter` will be 49 which is the code for 1.  As the program moves through the loop, `'0' + boardcounter` moves to 50 (the code for 2), 51 (the code for 3), and so on.

When boardcounter gets to 10, `'0' + boardcounter` will be 58 which is the code for :.  That's why you get that symbol in the image you posted.  Similar remarks apply when boardcounter is 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, and 16.

So now that the reason for the strange output is explained, the question is how to get the output you want.  One way is to use and if statement to check if boardcounter is between 1 and 9 or between 10 and 16.  If it's between 1 and 9, you can just use the code you posted.  If boardcounter is between 10 and 16, you might want to use a line like `board[i][j] = 'A' + (boardcounter-10);` to assign a character to the board array.